# Is there a way to implement transactions with PyQt5 and QMYSQL or QMYSQL3 drivers

Tags: mysql, pyqt5

Trying to implement transaction using PyQt5 QSqlDatabase connection to a MYSQL database. Both available drivers - QMYSQL and QMYSQL3 are operative but neither support transactions (db.driver().transaction(0) return False. Is there an available driver that support MYSQL transactions?

To update a two table inner join query, I found out that MYSQL does not support this operation type. My next try was to set the update in two queries included in one transaction - that is supported by MYSQL to find out that the available drivers don't support transactions.
So far I only tried to load both of the available drivers.

I guess a way to do it is to use Mysql connector but I'm afraid this may raise compatibility issues with PyQt5

I was able to solve partially the issue as part referring to MSQL not supporting join tables update. I was wrong, it simply was a codding mistake in my code. I included an extra bind value and generated a not too clear error message "Bind values not provided, QMYSQL3 could not run the query" or something similar. As soon as I matched the bound values it performed perfectly.

Nonetheless, I still need to figure out how to implement transactions in this environment. I certainly would have to use them. Momentarily, I only foresee: Making a custom Qt custom driver - complicated - ; Open a  Mysql.connector connection to the db for all operations requiring a transaction. - not very pretty; Try to use PyQt5 GUI with a db connection through MYSQL - which seems. not too documented and may be complicated. Hopefully  there is already a Qt driver for MYSQL. This would be great.

Comment: At what time are you doing the feature query? you must do it after opening the connection.

Comment: Yes, the queries are done on an already opend connection - QSQLDatabase -

Comment: What versions of PyQt5 and MySQL do you have? It works for me correctly

Comment: MySQL8.0 PyQt5 5.9